# How to remove gap between page and element

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the small gap between my footer and the web page on the left site but currently this is exceeding my capabilities I tried different ways like setting the width to 100% but none of them worked. The footer should fill the whole page vertically and should not remain a gap. How can I implement this?

```css
.options {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 313px;
  max-width: 750px;
  width: auto;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  height: 418.75%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 21px 25px 22px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16.8px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.button:hover,
#backward:hover,
#forward:hover {
  background-color: rgb(212, 21, 27);
  color: white;
}

.button-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.nav-inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 83px;
}

#backward {
  background-color: rgb(101, 93, 93);
  color: white;
}

#forward {
  background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}
```

```html
<div class="options">
  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="text">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="text">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="text">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="text">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="option">
    <div class="button">
      <div class="text">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="button-bar">
  <div class="nav-inner" id="backward">
    < zurück</div>
      <div class="nav-inner" id="forward">weiter ></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: By default, body has a margin. Add `body {margin: 0;}` and you will see your expected results

Comment: Thank you can You explain how or why that worked respectively

Comment: `body` has default styles by each browser. To avoid that situation, you need to reset them like `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` @madara030

Comment: Thank you Nick for the explanation whilst I was afk. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think you forgot to add "left" to your container

```css
.button-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```